# Iterate through several field strings

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm relatively new to C# and have more or less beginner/intermediate experience.

I'm developing a small sized console application in C#. It's meant to be an offline chat app (mostly experimenting purposes). I have a command for adding in members to this "room" in the chat app, I also have a command for showing all the currently connected members.

I have these variables in place for storing important people. I don't exactly know what the term for this kind of storage is:

```
var foundation = (Name: "Cool Founder", Rank: "FOUNDATION");
var developer = (Name: "Main Dev", Rank: "DEVELOPER");
var member = (Name: "John", Rank: "MEMBER");
```

Now, I may have several members and developers. It would look something like this:

```
var developer = (Name: "Sophie", Rank: "DEVELOPER");
var developer = (Name: "Aldrige", Rank: "DEVELOPER");
var member = (Name: "John", Rank: "MEMBER");
var member = (Name: "Hammond", Rank: "MEMBER");
var member = (Name: "Paul", Rank: "MEMBER");
```

What I would like to do here is iterate through all the `member` AND `developer` variables (both in one variable) and find the `Name` property for all 5. Perhaps a `foreach` loop of some sort?

A foreach loop could use something like `string names in member.Name`, but that would either only return one of the variables, or it would conflict because there are three variables with the same name, so I have struck that out of my book.

The problem is, I'm not sure how to go about this foreach loop with the first code I mentioned.

I could easily just write a List of strings (or make an `Array`) and integrate John, Hammond and Paul in there. However, I want to use the `Rank` property when using other commands and thus I require using this type of storage. What I have tried is `List<string> memberList = new List<string>();` and `string[] memberList = new string[3]{"John", "Hammond", "Paul"}` and the first code up above. Both the List and the Array work but as I said I require the `Rank` property for other usage such as showing suffixes or prefixes, or even display XP in the future.

The main purpose with this is to iterate through `foundation`, `developer` and `member` without needing to get the `Name` property from each variable **manually**. Aka foreach on all three with one variable.

Comment: You need declare a class with the properties `Name` and `Rank`, like `People`. Then you can manage a collection of people, like `List<People>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't exactly know what the term for this kind of storage is

Those are `ValueTuple`s.

> I want to use the `Rank` property when using other commands

You can create arrays of `ValueTuple`s as well:

```
var developers = new []
{
    (Name: "Sophie", Rank: "DEVELOPER"),
    (Name: "Aldrige", Rank: "DEVELOPER"),
};
```

Which can then be iterated:

```
foreach (var developer in developers)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{developer.Name} has rank: {developer.Rank}");
}
```

---

If you need the names of all developers and members, you could use LINQ:

```
var members = new []
{
    (Name: "John", Rank: "MEMBER"),
    (Name: "Hammond", Rank: "MEMBER"),
    (Name: "Paul", Rank: "MEMBER"),
};
    
var names = developers.Concat(members).Select(x => x.Name);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I realize why this works. However, is there any way to increment or add a new Name (with a Rank tied to it) to the developers Tuple? I just skimread the documentation of ValueTuple Struct and cannot find anything that would resemble the Add method.

Comment: If you need to add new developers you should replace the array with a list: `var developers = new List<(string Name, string Rank)>`. Then you can do: `developers.Add((Name: "Joe", Rank: "DEVELOPER"))`.

Comment: Ah alright. I'll try using that, thank you a lot!

Comment: Note that tuples are only appropriate for objects with limited scope; for a more extensible solution you should favour crating a new class.

Comment: To clarify, the first question I posted was mostly for adding in new **members** if I were to use a sort of registration system. Could come in handy in the future. Appreciate the help.

Understood that part, I read Tuples only have 8 scopes so I will not be using a lot of them.

Comment: Hi. Another question. I decided to use `var members = new List<(string Name, string Rank)>` as I require adding new members eventually. How would I fetch the Name if I have Hammond added but also have an additional 5 members? I don't know which index position he's in in the list.

Comment: You could do `var hammond = members.Single(x => x.Name == "Hammond")`, but you should really look at using a different data structure if you need to do such things regularly.